# XML XQUERY Problem with NTEXT data type

Tags: sql, xquery

I want to use XQuery on a column of data type NTEXT (I have no choice!). I have tried converting the column to XML using `CONVERT` but it gives the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.
```

Here's the query

```
SELECT 
    y.item.value('@UserID', 'varchar(50)') AS UnitID,   
    y.item.value('@ListingID', 'varchar(100)') AS @ListingID  
FROM   
    dbo.KB_XMod_Modules
    CROSS APPLY     
    CONVERT(xml, instancedata).nodes('//instance') AS y(item)
```

(instancedata is my column)

Can anyone think of a work around for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that neither `CONVERT` nor `CAST(... AS XML)` work.

The XQuery stuff really only works on XML columns - sorry.

However: maybe there's an escape route :-)

You could do one of two things:

- add a persisted computed column of type `XML` to your table and party on that new column

or - if you can't change the table structure -

- create a view over that table and include a XML-casted column

So for solution #1 you'd do:

```
ALTER TABLE KB_XMod_Modules 
   ADD XmlCol AS CAST(instancedata AS XML) PERSISTED
```

and for solution #2, you'd use:

```
CREATE VIEW KBwithXML AS
  SELECT instancedata, CAST(instancedata AS XML) 'XmlCol'
  FROM KB_XMod_Modules
```

In both cases, you now have a `XmlCol` of type `XML` available, which you can query with XQuery to your heart's delight!